# Python 32 or 64 on 64 bit Windows 7? How will this effect installing easy_install?

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, pip, windows-7-x64, easy-install

I wrote some python code on my mac and how I have to transfer it over to a windows computer. This is frustrating beyond words. I installed Python 2.7 x32, then I uninstalled it, then I installed Python 2.7 x64. My python script depends on xlrd and xlwt, and some other downloaded modules. I would like to install those using easy_install or pip or any way that is easy for somebody who doesn't know too much about the really intricate workings of a computer. As of now, if I do this:

```
C:\Windows\System32> python
```

I get:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.
```

[image: This is my python folder]

[image: This is the Scripts folder]

[image: These are my environment variables]

Would someone suggest a next move for me?

I did a bunch of google-ing and stackoverflow-ing and seem to have landed [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), I'm not sure how to download something from here. For example, how would I download Pip, and also, which one would I download?

People say that a person should download and install [this](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py), how would I do that?

I'm familiar with terminal, what would I type into cmd?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that I things were not going well for me was because I was using a mixture of Python 2.7 (32-bit) and Python 2.7 (64-bit). After more researching I found that even though my Windows 7 was 64 bit, I didn't have to download the 64-bit python. In fact, the 32-bit python was more compatible with other programs. So I clicked around and uninstalled python and everything else that had the name 'Python' in it from my Add/Remove programs menu. This took about 10 minutes. Next, I downloaded the 32-bit Python 2.7. After this, all of the packages that I download, I made sure that they were 32-bit and not 64-bit.

Also, very important, I went to my 'Environment Variables' (google how to get there) and added the directory of where Python27 was installed. To do this you can follow [this](http://pythoncentral.org/how-to-install-python-2-7-on-windows-7-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/) guide. The last thing that I did was add ;.PY to the end of PATHEXT.